How to set environment variables for .NET 8 Windows service?
Web applications have a web.config where I can set the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT variable.
I'm kinda used to deploying single project to different environments with using web.config transform that replaces the environment variable based on build configuration.
Is there something similar I can do for Windows services? Where based on build configuration, I can set the DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT variable? Or am I approaching Windows services from a wrong angle?
It would be nice if I could pass this environment variable via SC.exe while installing the service. Is that possible?

While web.config is used for web applications, Windows services can use appsettings.json for configuration. You can create different versions of appsettings.json for each environment, such as appsettings.Development.json, appsettings.Production.json, etc.

The question was how can I set that environment part of appsettings.{DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT}.json

The environment can be set as command line parameter during installation of the service (e.g. using PowerShell New-Service or sc.exe).
When providing the path to your service-executable you can add --environment <environment>, where  must be the name of your appropriate DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT, like Development or Production.
New-Service -Name "MyWindowsService" -BinaryPathName "C:\Path\To\App.exe --environment Development"

or with sc.exe (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/windows-service#create-the-windows-service):
sc.exe create "MyWindowsService" binpath="C:\Path\To\App.exe --environment Development"

